# Text Decryption - Shifting goes wrong

Tags: c++

I'm working on a Shit Cipher and decrypting a particular piece of text. Ok, so, how the program works:

1. Takes the characters from a text file
2. Shift each of the characters 9 places down the alphabet.

Now, I have done this, however, I know that the character cannot be shift always by 9 places, so the program looks at where the character is in the alphabet char array and then if it can be done, it just adds 9, and if it cannot be done, it just takes 9 away (Finds the difference). But, it's not working and I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
using namespace std;

string inputFile = "";
#define MAX_FILE_SIZE 10000
const char alphabet[26] =   {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
const char alphabetUpper[26] =   
{'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};

const int sizeAlpha = sizeof(alphabet)/sizeof(alphabet[0]);
void Data(char* theData)
{
ifstream txtFile(inputFile.c_str());
if(!txtFile.is_open())
{
    cerr << "Cannot open text file";
}
txtFile.read(theData, 520);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

char getData[MAX_FILE_SIZE];

Data(getData);

char decrypted[520];

int algorthm;

for(unsigned i=0; (i < 520); i++)
{
    for(unsigned j=0; (j < 26); j++)
    {
        if(getData[i] == alphabet[j] || alphabetUpper[j])
        {
            algorthm = j + 9; // we move 9 places.

            if(sizeAlpha < algorthm)
            {
                decrypted[i] = alphabet[algorthm];

            }else if(algorthm > sizeAlpha || algorthm == sizeAlpha) 
            {
                algorthm = sizeAlpha - j;

                decrypted[i] = alphabet[algorthm];
            }
        }
    }
}

for(unsigned i=0; (i < 520); i++)
{
    cout << decrypted[i]; 
}
}
```

Anyone know where I'm going wrong, or, can offer a simular solution?

Comment: "I'm working on a Shit Cipher" - that's your problem right there! =)

Comment: hahahaha that was funny :) Well done!

Comment: I'm a little disappointed that the typo has been corrected.  Now it looks like I'm just making a lame joke.

Comment: To save you keystrokes, write your arrays as `const char alphabetUpper[] = {"ABCDEFGH..."};`.

Comment: Thanks for everyones reply! @paddy thanks for making me giggle :')!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if it can be done, it just adds 9, and if it cannot be done, it just takes 9 away

That cannot possibly be reversible, because you map two different values to the same one.

Instead, you have to wrap around:

```
unsigned char shiftChar(unsigned char const plain, signed char const by) {
  unsigned char const caseBit = plain & ('a' ^ 'A');
  unsigned char offset = (plain ^ caseBit) - ('a' & 'A');
  offset += ('z' - 'a' + 1) + by; // there's your "shift"
  offset %= ('z' - 'a' + 1);
  return caseBit | (offset + ('a' & 'A'));
}
```

Comment: This can also reverse the encryption; `shiftChar(x,9)` encrypts while `shiftChar(x,-9)` decrypts a single character.

Comment: Hey thank you, but, I don't get what the "by" is.. I'm guessing plain is the plain text?

Comment: @Phorce: I'm not suggesting you copy/paste this. Try to understand what's going on there. The second argument should become clear then. Especially if you have a look at my previous comment.

Comment: `by` is just a signed number (the amount to shift *by*).  It happens to be `char` type because that's all that is necessary.  It also matches the type of `plain`, which is more correct than using `int` or whatever.

Comment: I get it now, it just confused me because it was a char, instead of an int.. But I get it :) Thank you! Hopefully, I've figured this out.

Comment: @paddy: What `char` is depends on the compiler (flags). You can have it default to `signed char` (which is usually the case) but also to the unsigned version. In any case, I added the `signed` keyword as a means of documentation, that you are *supposed* to pass a signed value. -- On a side remark, character literals have type `int`, not `char` in C :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to do modulo:

```
algorthm = (j + 9) % 26;
```

If you take away 9 to handle the overflow, then you will introduce clashes with other characters and the first 9 places will not be used.

*[edit]* Just to point out...

There's also a problem with your if-statement:

```
if(getData[i] == alphabet[j] || alphabetUpper[j])
```

This doesn't work the way you think it does, and if it did your algorithm wouldn't work anyway because you don't later distinguish between upper and lower case.  You would have to duplicate your code or set a pointer to the correct array.  But that's the long way around.

You don't need to search through an array of alphabet characters in order to do the test.  Any sensible character encoding (and I would say ASCII is by far the most common) will keep alpha characters in order.  So:

```
const int shiftAmt = 9;
char c = getData[i];

if( c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' )
    c = 'A' + ((c - 'A' + shiftAmt) % 26);
else if( c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' )
    c = 'a' + ((c - 'a' + shiftAmt) % 26);

decrypted[i] = c;
```

Note that this also preserves any non-alphabet characters, whereas your code forgot about them and left that position in the 'decrypted' array uninitialised.

Comment: Now it doesn't print out anything!! haha

Comment: See my edits.  I think you probably have other code issues.  You don't get any output because both your tests in the inner loop check for `sizeAlpha` being less than `algorthm` (or equal, for the second test) .  That can never happen with modulo.  Forgive me if I shifted in the wrong direction in my code.  If you want to shift the other way, add `26 - shiftAmt` (provided that `shiftAmt` is 26 or less).

Comment: A faster way to do this is to skip the tests altogether during decoding.  You can generate a 256-char array (either statically or dynamically) that maps one char to the other.  You can have one for each direction.  *ie* `char encMap[256], decMap[256]`.  Then you just do this: `decrypted[i] = decMap[(unsigned)getData[i]];`